# Incorrect results when matching multiple labels with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that has nodes that represent roles in a permission hierarchy. The permission hierarchy looks like this:

```
(:role:owners)-[:CONTACT]->(:role:admins)-[:CONTACT]->(:role:employees)
-[:CONTACT]->(:role:contacts)
```

Contacts are then attached to each of the role nodes like this:

```
(:contact {id: "1"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:owners)
(:contact {id: "2"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:employees)
```

I'm trying to run the following query that returns the `:contacts` role if the user is an owner or an admin (such as contact 1) and the `:employees` role if the user is an employee (such as contact 2).

```
MATCH (c:contact {id: "1"})
WITH c

MATCH (g:role)
WHERE
  (c)-[:CONTACT*1..2]->(:admins)-->(:employees)-->(g:contacts) OR
  (c)-[:CONTACT]->(g:employees)
RETURN DISTINCT c, g
```

Expected result

```
c                          g
(:contact {id: "1"})       (:role:contacts)
Returned 1 row
```

Actual result

```
c                          g
(:contact {id: "1"})       (:role:owners)
(:contact {id: "1"})       (:role:admins)
(:contact {id: "1"})       (:role:employees)
(:contact {id: "1"})       (:role:contacts)
Returned 4 rows
```

I thought this query would only return nodes with both the `:role` label and either `:contacts` or `:employees` but instead it also returns nodes with `:owners` and `:admins` labels.

Why is it returning these extra nodes and how can I prevent it from doing so? This is for Neo4j 2.1.2.

**Additional Information**

I think I've found the bug. Looks like the label check is being dropped if a valid path is not found. In the following example, note that there is no path between `(c1)` and `(g:projectcontacts)` since there are no `(:projectcontacts)` nodes.  In this case, the `projectcontacts` match is dropped and all nodes that match `(c1)-[:CONTACT*1..3]->(g:role)` are returned instead.

This is on a Neo4j 2.1.3 server:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE
>   (o:role:owners {name:"Owners"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:admins {name:"Admins"})-[:CONTACT]->
>   (e:role:employees {name:"Employees"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:contacts {name:"Contacts"})
> CREATE
>   (c1:contact {id: "test1"})-[:CONTACT]->(o)
> CREATE
>   (c2:contact {id: "test2"})-[:CONTACT]->(e)
> 
> WITH c1
> 
> MATCH (g:role)
> WHERE
>   (c1)-[:CONTACT*1..2]->(:admins)-->(:employees)-->(g:contacts) OR
>   (c1)-[:CONTACT]->(g:employees) OR
>   (c1)-[:CONTACT*1..3]->(g:projectcontacts)
> RETURN DISTINCT c1, g;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| c1                     | g                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[4439]{id:"test1"} | Node[4438]{name:"Contacts"}  |
| Node[4439]{id:"test1"} | Node[4436]{name:"Admins"}    |
| Node[4439]{id:"test1"} | Node[4437]{name:"Employees"} |
| Node[4439]{id:"test1"} | Node[4435]{name:"Owners"}    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows
Nodes created: 6
Relationships created: 5
Properties set: 6
Labels added: 10
50 ms
```

If we drop the non-existant node label from our match query, we get the expected results.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ CREATE
>   (o:role:owners {name:"Owners"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:admins {name:"Admins"})-[:CONTACT]->
>   (e:role:employees {name:"Employees"})-[:CONTACT]->(:role:contacts {name:"Contacts"})
> CREATE
>   (c1:contact {id: "test1"})-[:CONTACT]->(o)
> CREATE
>   (c2:contact {id: "test2"})-[:CONTACT]->(e)
> 
> WITH c1
> 
> MATCH (g:role)
> WHERE
>   (c1)-[:CONTACT*1..2]->(:admins)-->(:employees)-->(g:contacts) OR
>   (c1)-[:CONTACT]->(g:employees)
> RETURN DISTINCT c1, g;
+------------------------------------------------------+
| c1                     | g                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[4445]{id:"test1"} | Node[4444]{name:"Contacts"} |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
Nodes created: 6
Relationships created: 5
Properties set: 6
Labels added: 10
55 ms
```

Comment: can you give us some sample output? you mean you're getting more than expected in `g`, right?

Comment: Correct.  Instead of just returning the `:role:contacts` node it also returns the intermediate `:role:owners`, `:role:admins`, and `:role:employees` nodes. I updated the question with results.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, somehow the pattern isn't also filtering on the label. Does it fix it if you add an additional constraint, like `WHERE (g:contacts) OR (g:employees) WITH g` before that? Any chance of getting some sample data in console or something?

Comment: Could you check if it's the same with 2.1.3?

Comment: I've updated the question.  I think I found the bug and it still exists in 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

I don't know this for sure, but I would tend to guess that the problem is that you are causing g to be redefined by adding labels to it in your WHERE clause. Having a label applied may cause g to be viewed as a pattern to be matched.

Whether that is right or wrong, here is a way to do the query that doesn't run afoul of the problem (now corrected to do what you are wanting to do):

```
MATCH (c1:contact {id : 'test'})
WITH c1
MATCH (c1)-[:CONTACT]->(f:role)-[:CONTACT*1..]->(g:contacts)
WITH c1, CASE WHEN 'employees' IN labels(f) THEN f ELSE g END AS h
RETURN DISTINCT c1, h
```

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: In my case, g is a pattern to be matched. The odd part is that it works as expected as long as the labels are in the path, once a label is introduced that isn't in the path, it reverts to incorrect behavior. While you're query works, it doesn't return the results that I'm looking for unfortunately.

Comment: The MATCH(g:role) clause fixes g to a particular collection of nodes. The use of g in your WHERE clause with a different label may cause it to be treated as an unfixed part of a pattern, rather than a fixed anchor.

Comment: Doh! I totally missed on that query! I modified the query in the answer to make it do what you were asking to do.